# Inequality of Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

We all know that on $\mathbb R$,
$$
\|\hat f\|_\infty\leq \|f\|_1.
$$
In particular, equality holds if $f\geq 0$, but in most of the cases we have strict inequality. But is the following true: for every $\epsilon>0$, there is an $0\neq f\in L^1$ with 
$$
\|\hat f\|_\infty\leq \epsilon\|f\|_1?
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's define $f_n(x)$ piecewise by $f_n(x) = e^{2\pi i k x}$ if $0\leq k < x < k+1 \leq n$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $\lVert f\rVert_1 = 2\pi n$, but
$$|\widehat {f_n}(\xi)| = \left| \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-2\pi i \xi x}f(x) dx\right| = \left|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \int_0^{1}e^{2\pi i (k-\xi) (x+k)}dx\right|\leq \\\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |e^{2\pi i k(k-\xi)}|\frac{\left|e^{2\pi i (k-\xi)}-1\right|}{2\pi |k-\xi|} = \mathcal O(\ln(n)).$$
Thus, $\lVert \widehat{f_n} \rVert_\infty \leq \frac{C\ln n}{n}\lVert f_n \rVert_1$ for some $C$ independent of $n$. The idea here was to construct a function which "resonates" with no particular frequency, such that it's fourier transform takes no large values.

Comment: Why was your second integral from 0 to 1 but not from $k$ to $k+1$?

Comment: @SingfookSangwood My mistake, I did a substitution in my head that wasn't really possible that way (shifting the limits of the integral). Doesn't change anything, though.